# Android AlertDialog: How to hide the activity behind it?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm looking for a way to hide the underlying activity of an AlertDialog.

I tried to set a solid overlay color but it looks like there are no default methods for doing this. Is there a way to do this without creating a new activity with a solid background color that then fires the dialog?

I couldn't find anything other than doing it by firing a whole new activity on StackOverFlow, google, the android documentation and the AlertDialog API page but this seems like overkill.

Ideally I'm looking for something like `alert.setOverlayColor(int color)`

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom layout for the Dialog with height and width as "match_parent". Use the area required by dialog and put a solid background in the top level.

Comment: For some reason this didn't show up in my feed but I'll try it and get back to you. Thanks!